# C++ unable to print the char variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, type-conversion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char ch[10];
  ch = getch();
  cout << ch;
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘char [10]’
>
> ch=getch();

Comment: `ch` is a character array, not a character (which can be casted to `int`).

Comment: You also didn't explain what you were trying to do, so it's unclear whether you want to get/print one `char` or a string of them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it currently stands, your question could use more explanation so we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Randomly mashing your keys into a text editor does not a valid C++ program make. You have to actually engage your _brain_ and _think_ about what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

> C++ unable to print the char variable
>
> ```
> char ch[10];
> ```

`ch` is not a "`char` variable". It is a `char` **array** variable. Array variables can not be assigned to.

Perhaps you intended to have a char variable instead:

```
 char ch;
```

The value of a `char` can be assigned.

Answer (score 2):

`getch()` returns int (or char). You declared:

```
char ch[10];
```

which is a character array not a single character that cannot be cast to an int. This throws an error.

It can be corrected by changing:

```
char ch[10];
```

to:

```
char ch;
```

By changing it, you are declaring a character `ch` instead of a character array.

Answer (score 0):

ch[10]  is a character array, it's not a single character. getch() read a single byte character from input.so try following code.

```
int main()
    {
    char ch;
    ch = getch();
    cout << ch; 
    }
```